# Slow transfer speeds from external hard disk to laptop

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ssd, external-hdd, transfer

I have a WD My Passport 2 TB, when I copy files from my PC to this hard disk (Windows 7, Seagate 2TB Barracuda HDD) I get speeds of about 100 MBps.

But when I transfer files from the hard disk to my laptop (Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3, SSD ([Laptop Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M18UZF5))), I cap out at 30 MBps. I've tried using the GUI copy as well as rsync.

I'm using USB 3.0 ports on both PC and Laptop.

The external HDD is formatted as NTFS.

What could be the limitation here? These are the exact same files (large video files mostly) which I copied first from PC to HDD, and then from HDD to Laptop.

Comment: It could be the linux driver for the `NTFS` file system. My experience is that read/write operations from/to linux file systems are much faster. I have seen this with hard disk drives connected via eSATA.  Can you test with an `ext4` file system on the same drive (and via USB 3)?

Comment: I will try this, but any idea whether ext4 to windows copy speeds are slow? Because that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Well, that is a problem. If you want to share data between Ubuntu and Windows, I would recommend `NTFS` because I think the drivers for `ext4` in Windows are not quite reliable (at least not for writing).

Comment: If you want to transfer files between the two computers, you can do it via a local area network, LAN. It is easy to install **openssh-server** in Ubuntu and then connect via sftp or filezilla or winscp from Windows. With a fast LAN you can get faster and more convenient file transfer compared to what you get via USB 3 and NTFS. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring -- You can use it with password authentication directly, but you may want to increase the security and use SSH keys.

Comment: I made an ext4 partition on the hard disk, now my speeds from HDD -> Laptop have improved to 50 MBps, however Laptop -> HDD is still at 30 MBps.

Comment: The laptop does not have an ethernet port, and copying over WIFI gives me speeds of 3-4 MBps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64837/discussion-between-sudodus-and-cerberus).

Comment: Let us continue in the automatically created chat room.

Comment: We need input from **you**. Please chip in with your tips how to understand and if possible help Cerberus solve this problem.